# When might you say 借你吉言？

Tags: usage

In what kind of situations might I use the phrase 借你吉言？

Edit: I'm trying to think of a neat, cool translation. Haven't got one yet!

Maybe:

God willing

If only ...

Comment: When someone says any good luck thing to you, predicting you are going to get some good results, you can reply with it.

Answer (score 1):

> 字典中解释为:接受你的祝福，谢谢你的关照

You can use it when somebody say something good about you or when something good comes true which was said by somebody.

例子1:

> A:你家孩子学习这么好，肯定能考个好大学
>
> B:借你吉言…………

例子2:

> A :昨天晚上有点感冒
>
> B:今天天气这么好，肯定会很快就好的
>
> 第二天A的感冒好了，两人又见面了
>
> A:借你吉言，昨天感冒真的好多了

Comment: It can translate as "Thanks for your good will for me" or "I get a good result for what you said before"

Answer (score 1):

It is used when someone said something good is going to happen to you (or you family etc.).

For example:

A: 你肯定能通过这次考试！

B: 借你吉言，我也希望能通过！

Answer (score 1):

> 承你貴言
> http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/56723/
>
> "**wish everything you said would come true**"

承你貴言 is a more well known idiom than 借你吉言.

I only heard 借你吉言 for the first time here. It is virtually unknown among Cantonese.

The two phrases are very similar in meaning though,

- 借你吉言 means "(I hope to)borrow your blessing words "
- 承你貴言 means " (I) humbly accept your blessing words and hope it will come true"

You can use either phrase as a formal / humble respond, when someone is :

- (1.) blesses you good luck
- (2.) predicts good fortune or success will come to you.

But I suggest using the more common 承你貴言.